# Graphing folium of Descartes

Tags: geometry

Is there a computer program that will graph the equations of such figures as the witch of Agnesi and the folium of Descartes? -- Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best free mathematical engine I've used, by far, is [Wolfram|Aplha](http://wolframalpha.com). This service allows you to graph pretty much any named curve and gives you a lot of properties of each one. It also calculates a lot of different things that usually a calculator either couldn't or wouldn't be effective at. Wolfram also has a reference library which explains a lot of different mathematical concepts (although at a high level).

Answer (score 0):

[desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jwyvv0ze7a) produces very nice pictures and supports dynamic changes of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[GeoGebra](http://download.geogebra.org) will plot those nicely, and you can also find pre-made versions on [GeoGebra Materials](http://www.geogebra.org/search/perform/search/witch%20of%20Agnesi)